# Git GUI Crash Signal 6

Tags: xcode, git, git-gui

I am using git version 1.9.2 with Xcode6-Beta3.

At beginning, git gui works properly.

For some reason (which I don't know...)

when typing "git gui" on Terminal,

I got the following crash message:

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Error (1000) creating window shape'

SOME CALL STACK INFO

libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
error: git-gui died of signal 6

Most suggestions I found are about "git-gui died of signal 11".

Please let me know if any suggestion or question.

Thank you for precious time on my question (or crash)

Comment: Signal 6 is an assertion being raised, aka `SIGABRT`. You are using a beta program. Post a message on the Apple Developer Forums and file a bug.

Comment: Hello Jason, Thank for the suggestion. I did it!

Answer (score 64):

This appears to happen when git-gui can't create the window in its last position.  In my case, it is because the window location is negative.  I have multiple monitors, one of which is to the upper left of the primary.

You can unset it with this:

```
git config --local --unset gui.geometry
```

The other answer "works" because it doesn't take the config into account.  It avoids the issue, but doesn't actually fix it.

Comment: This alone is not enough, but apparently reduces the frequency of crash.

Comment: @tom-kerr, you are a hero of the first order.

Comment: This should be the selected answer.  Thanks @tom-kerr

Comment: Also solved my "Error in startup script: bad geometry specifier" problem when starting "git gui"

Answer (score 4):

I found a way to use git GUI in this situation. Instead of launching git GUI on the directory of the git repository by the terminal, you can launch git GUI on other directory and use "Open Existing Respository" to open the directory of the git repository.

Please let me know if any question.