# I can't run `git gui` on macOs Big Sur

Tags: macos-big-sur, git-gui

When I run `git gui` on Mac Big Sur . This is what happen :

```
Mac OS X 10.100 or later required !
error: git-gui died of signal 6
```

I also install `xcode 12 beta 3` and `xcodebuild -version` stays `Xcode 11.6` .

How can I solve those problems ?

Comment: If one of these answers helped or is correct, can you mark it as such?

Answer (score 2):

A variety of things I had to do to fix this:

Update tcl (not sure if this was required for `git gui`, but it was necessary for `gitk`):

```
 brew install tcl
```

Install git-gui directly:

```
brew install git-gui
```

Ensure macOS is using the correct `git` (assuming here that you have already installed a version from this decade):

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:${PATH}"
```

Comment: May you explain about the latest command? I'm not familiar with it that much.

Comment: It depends a bit on your environment, but the point is, to make sure when you run `git version`, that you are running the version you are expecting to run / most recent available. If you are not, then you'll want to go back to installing git and follow those instructions (which will explain the last command).

Comment: ``macOS 11 or later required !
error: git-gui died of signal 6``


works for big sur 

``Solved it by running brew install tcl``

Comment: Unfortunately, this fix didn't work for me. `git version` gives me 2.16.12 but `git gui` still crashes.

Comment: Thank you @TylerA. `brew upgrade git` installed git 2.30.0 and fixed the issue. (The issue was the `error: git-gui died of signal 6` crash described in the question. Yes, this was a crash complete with stack trace and Crash Reporter Dialog.)

Answer (score 1):

It's working again on macOS Big Sur 11.2 (20D64)

Just need to update your OS

Update: After a while, the issue happened again even after I update my macOS to 11.2.1 (20D74). But with a different message who said there is an unmatched exception "NSInternalInconsistencyException".

```
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid parameter not satisfying: CGRectContainsRect(CGRectMake((CGFloat)INT_MIN, (CGFloat)INT_MIN, (CGFloat)INT_MAX - (CGFloat)INT_MIN, (CGFloat)INT_MAX - (CGFloat)INT_MIN), frame)'
```

I fix it with:

`git config --local --unset gui.geometry`

that mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25246261/3086080)

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem after the update, so I ran

```
brew install git
```

as a temporary solution.

Answer (score -1):

Run the following command in Terminal: defaults write com.apple.dt.Xcode DVTDisableMainThreadChecker 1

Answer (score -1):

I have the same problem and I have tried to fix it and finally, it works for me with these steps.

--

Make sure you have installed the last version of git

```
brew upgrade git
```

and after this, you may need to link the new version of git

```
brew link git
```

the last step update and link `git-gui` at this step I install `git-gui` from this command

```
brew install git-gui
```

then link it with this command

```
brew link git-gui
```